# Is my understanding of modern IDEs autosave feature naive?

Tags: design, performance, files, text-processing

Long time ago I learned that text files are not like Random access Files, i. e., adding or updating info at the beginning of a text file involves moving all the rest of the file "forward" (or backwards if the size of the new info is smaller than the former info) in storage to let some space. This takes time and space in memory, even using buffers.

Moreover modern IDEs seem to flush all the buffers when saving files in case a failure occurs.

My point is: Am I right presuming that editing a huge text file with autosave enabled is slower when done at the beginning of the file or are there some tricks involved I'm not aware of?

Maybe the lack of really fast secondary storage (like SSD) until a few years ago made this autosave not so common? Can anybody perhaps enlighten me?

I've read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273524/336500 but I'd prefer an answer from the point of view of a programmer, like

What type of File Decorator would you use to implement autosave feature in Java?, for example.

Comment: Are you entirely sure that Autosave will work with `a huge text file`? Saving a 10MB file will take just a second, but I doubt IDEs will really attempt autosaves on 1G files

Comment: What do you consider huge?  The largest single source code file I've ever seen was about 20,000 lines long, which *might* be pushing a megabyte.  You only have to autosave files that have been changed or added, and programmers can only type so fast.  Seriously, it's *not* a heavy lift.

Comment: So, autosave was not an option 20 years ago due to the slow hardware we had which is not a problem nowadays, I'm I right?

Comment: I seem to remember having auto-save in some tools 20 years ago.  "Slow" is a relative term, the machines I was using to write code 20 years ago were way faster than the machines I used to write code 30 years ago.

Comment: `So, autosave was not an option 20 years ago due to the slow hardware we had which is not a problem nowadays, I'm I right?` -- Hard to say.  Maybe we just hadn't thought of it yet.

Comment: Autosave has been around in Emacs for decades.  At any rate, is this actually something that needs optimization?

Comment: Most editor's save features have to write files from the beginning because most text editors don't actually overwrite files, but rather they write to a new temporary file, then rename/move them over the saved file. This is so that if the editor crashes while saving the file, you aren't left with corrupted partial file.

Answer (score 0):

> adding or updating info at the beginning of a text file involves moving all the rest of the file "forward"

Only if you have a the simplest possible in-memory implementation. It would, for example, be easy to store a text file as a linked list of lines. Now, adding text at the start of the file is just a matter of prepending a new line to the linked list.

Comment: *[shrug]* See my comment above.

Comment: But if you have to "flush" to secondary memory the list, It really doen't matter your in-memory implementation, at last things will work as I thought. Thank you.

Comment: @Mdot And who's saying that your on-disk representation isn't also a linked list-style? Add a line in the middle? Navigate to exactly that row on the disk, modify the "next" data, append new line at the end of storage with "next" pointing to the line that should come next.